# How does tastypie handle comlex url?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Tastypie can automatically generate urlpattern for simple resource urls.

For example, `/user/1/` , `/group/2/`, I only need to define UserResource and GroupResource

But what if I have API url like `/group/2/user/`, saying I want to retrieve all users in group 2.

Does tastypie have any solution to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`tastypie.Resource.prepend_urls`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L315) method:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from tastypie.utils import trailing_slash

class MyResource(Resource):
    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<%s>.*?)/user%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, self._meta.detail_uri_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('group_user'), name="api_group_user"),
        ]

    def group_user(self, request, **kwargs):
        # Your API view.
        return self.create_response(request, {})
```

I usually create a shortcut method that those long, ugly urls:

```
def create_detail_url(url_string, view_method_name, view_name):
    url_string = r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<%s>.*?)" + url_string + r"%s$"
    url_string = url_string % (self._meta.resource_name, self._meta.detail_uri_name, trailing_slash())
    return url(url_string, self.wrap_view(view_method_name), name="api_" + view_name)
```

Which makes the `prepend_urls` method look like this:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
    return [
        create_detail_url(r"/user", "group_user", "group_user"),
    ]
```

Comment: Well, It seems that ^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<%s>.*?)/user%s$  could not be reached, because the original DETAIL url, namely ^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<%s>\w[\w/-]*)%s$ will take over it.

Comment: @EricZheng, the `prepend_urls` method inserts the result list _before_ the regular urls thus they take precedence over regular urls. You can check by adding a custom view to the detail url in the `prepend_urls`.